# I think my regular expression pattern in C# is incorrect

Tags: c#, regex

I'm checking to see if my regular expression matches my string.
I have a filename that looks like `somename_somthing.txt` and I want to match it to `somename_*.txt`, but my code is failing when I try to pass something that should match. Here is my code.

```
string pattern = "somename_*.txt";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
using (ZipFile zipFile = ZipFile.Read(fullPath))
{
   foreach (ZipEntry e in zipFile)
   {
       Match m = r.Match("somename_something.txt");
       if (!m.Success)
       {
           throw new FileNotFoundException("A filename with format: " + pattern + " not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think title of this post is not reflecting the problem.

Comment: please recommend what it should be and I'll change it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**In General**

Regex give in this code matches the _ with an * meaning zero or more underscores instead of what you intended. The * is used to denote zero or more of the previous item. Instead try

```
^somename_(.*)\.txt$
```

This matches exactly the first part "somename_".

Then anything (.*)

And finally the end ".txt". The backslash escapes the 'dot'.

**More Specific**

You can also say if you only want letters and not numbers or symbols in the middle part of the match with:

```
^somename_[a-z]*\.txt$
```

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk is matching the underscore and throwing it off.

Try:

```
somename_(\w+).txt
```

The (\w+) here will match the group at this location.

You can see it match here: https://regex101.com/r/qS8wA5/1

Answer (score 0):

As written, your regular expression

```
somename_*.txt
```

matches (in a case-insensitive manner):

- the literal text `somename`, followed by
- zero or more underscore characters (`_`), followed
- any character (other than newline), followed
- the literal text `txt`

And it will match that *anywhere* in the source text. You probably want to write something like

```
Regex myPattern = new Regex( @"
    ^        # anchor the match to start-of-text, followed by
    somename # the literal 'somename', followed by
    _        # a literal underscore character, followed by
    .*       # zero or of any character (except newline), followed by
    \.       # a literal period/fullstop, followed by
    txt      # the literal text 'txt' 
    $        # with the match anchored at end-of-text
  " , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase|RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
  ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think the pattern should be

```
string pattern = "somename_.*\\.txt";
```

Regards

Comment: You may also force the "positioning" of the string with "^somename_.*\\.txt$"

This will fails for "a_somename_something.txt"

Comment: It doesn't do what he wants it to do.

Comment: Thanks @JBlaz, your comment "That doesn't work" and  "It doesn't do what he wants it to do" really helped me to understand what I'm doing wrong (if so). I tested my code with a set of data and It works fine. It depends of the  "degree of precision" the OP wants.

Comment: The ONLY text your regex matches is "somename_.\.txt" with 1 or more slashes. Hence, the "That doesn't work" comment. The reason it does this is because there is no wild card group and .* doesn't match anything. The 2 slashes escape each other and does not match the dot in .txt like I think you wanted. So remove one slash and group up the .* and it works fine but as is it, and I quote, "doesn't do what he wants it to do".

Comment: I think you misunderstood my pattern. In fact it matches the following : "somename_name.txt", "somename_somename.zip.txt", "something_somename_name.txt". It doesn't match the following : "somename_name.tif", "somename.txt", "somename_". Dont forget I don't use verbatim string (like in the original question), so I need to use an extra slash to escape the other. You also don't need grouping for your dot. The star is applied to the preceding character so ".*" equals "(.)*", but I think the last one will capture the characters occuring in the dot (I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: I dont know what you are using to test your regex but this question is tagged c# so it was to work with c# and yours does not do that in c#. Allow me to show you. http://i245.photobucket.com/albums/gg59/1ruleyou/Untitled_1.png the link shows how it does not match what you said. And this one shows how it does what I said. http://i245.photobucket.com/albums/gg59/1ruleyou/Untitled_1.png

Comment: Yeah it's C#. Please check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B647BUIdP3EoY09YMUFFdXdEcjA/view?pli=1

Comment: Interesting. I would run it on my computer but This topic is taking way too long!